# Hiding a specific app from start menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu, regedit, adobe-creative-cloud

I am having a little situation where after installing Adobe Creative Cloud on my computer an app called "Notification Manager for Adobe Creative Cloud" appeared on my Start Menu. I have checked in both "all user start menu" and "current user start menu" folders, but it seems that there is no shortcut to that application. I have tried to uninstall the app but after a while it was reinstalled automatically once again. I know that some apps can be hidden by using the "Registry Editor", but I forgot exactly in which folder I should go to. If you can help me I would be really grateful. Thank you in advance and I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: If you right-click on the shortcut in the Start Menu, do you see the option to Open File Location?

Comment: @music2myear, Sadly, not. That's why I think the only way to hide it would be through finding the record at the Registry Editor and disabling it. However, if you have any other suggestions I would love to hear them. It's a very confusing app!

Comment: What do you mean by it being a "very confusing app" and why do you wish it hidden? I'd guess Adobe Updater reinstall the app.

Comment: @music2myear, I am suspecting the same thing, from what I found on the internet the application is necessary for the Adobe Creative Cloud to function properly or at least that’s what I found on the official Adobe’s forum. Thus, if Adobe Updater (or Adobe Creative Cloud) detects that this application is missing it automatically reinstalls back to the PC. However, from the behavior of the application I am assuming that it was designed to be a background process, because when you try to open the application the Adobe Creative Cloud application opens instead.

Comment: That is why I think this might be the reason for me to cannot right click on it and select "open file location" and the only way to kind of bodge this thing would be through the "Registry Editor". In regards, to why I want it hidden, because it's literally useless and I would like when I press start menu to have application that I use and hide the ones that I would never need. It's just a personal preference and slight productivity improvement.

Comment: That is why I thought there must be something similar that relates to the start menu. Once again, thank you very much and it seems that I would have an interesting side-project to do as a new year’s present, ha-ha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102914/discussion-between-pimp-juice-it-and-george-smith).

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, I just used that as an example of how to hide something through the Registry Editor. Unfortunately, in my case it is not solving my problem, but I thought it might be something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an "Unpin from Start Menu" option when you right-click on the icon in the Start Menu? Or are you talking about the icon in the All Apps section of the Start Menu? If the former, you can unpin it.

Comment: Sadly, I am referring to the All Apps section :(